# how to input validation message in a cell from text box in userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a data entry form for sample analysis.

For 1 test there's several criteria. Thus, I plan to create a validation message pop up for the information keyed in from a text box.

Initially it works but after a while an error message 1004 keep popping up and there's no validation message pop up in the cell selected.

```
If Userform.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(J, 19).Interior.Color = vbYellow
With ActiveCell.Offset(J, 19).Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
 .InputTitle = "additional info"
 .InputMessage = Userform.TextBox9.Text
End With
End If
```

Initially when this code works, when I key in the data in text box 9, the active cell is highlight and there's a validation message pop up when you select the cell.

Now the active cell still highlight but there's no validation message pop up for additional info.

Not sure why last time it works but now it doesn't.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing more of the code.  What is _J_?

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error when you try to set a validation to a cell that has already a validation.

Simply removing the existing validation (with method `.Delete`) before setting it will prevent the 1004 error:

```
With ActiveCell.Offset(J, 19).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
    .InputTitle = "additional info"
    .InputMessage = Userform.TextBox9.Text
End With
```